# How to change query in a Loader<Cursor> after notifyChange

Tags: android, loader, android-cursor

I have tried for hours but couldn't achieve this. I tried sending via Bundle, via static variables, via if statement but nothing worked.

I have a situation where I want my Loader to load different sets of data once user has clicked a menu item. This means the query should be changed once it has received the notifyChange. The code is pretty standard Loader code like this:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String query = args.getString("query");

    String[] projection = { DbCreate.ID, DbCreate.COL_ITEM, DbCreate.COL_STATUS, DbCreate.COL_SYNCED,
            DbCreate.COL_PRIORITY, DbCreate.COL_COMPLETEBY, DbCreate.COL_TAG, DbCreate.COL_ASSIGNED, DbCreate.COL_SHARED};

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            DbProvider.CONTENT_URI_DATA, projection, query, null, "priority DESC, status ASC, _id DESC");

    return cursorLoader;
}
```

I tried usual if(...) statement inside this onCreate method too but it doesn't work. This means the notifyChange just triggers the already created object. So how can I  inject a new 'query' value on the notifyChange?

Comment: From the sounds of it, you'll be loading a completely new dataset. Would it not make more sense to destroy the current loader and initialise a new one? Based on the state (that follows from selecting a menu item) you can then return a `CursorLoader` with a query appropriate to the selection.

Answer (score 9):

I am doing same thing in my code you need to restart cursor loader again when you want to change the data notify works on adapter not on cursor loader

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle arg1) {
        // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created. 
        // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
        // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
        Uri contentUri = MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_FACEBOOK;
        switch (id) {
        case FACEBOOK:
            contentUri = MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_FACEBOOK;
            break;
        case LINKEDIN:
            contentUri = MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_LINKEDIN;
            break;
        }

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), contentUri, null, null, null,
                null);

    }
```

for various queries I am doing like this only

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(FACEBOOK, null, Profile.this);
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LINKEDIN, null, Profile.this);
```

so you just need to restart loader

Comment: Yes, `restartLoader()` is exactly what I had been missing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you probably don't want to worry about trying to change the dataset via notifyChange. I think you most likely want to simply fire-off a new loader (or do a forced reload on the existing one). Let the loader set the adapter on load completion and that will cause a notify on the data set.

I.E. User clicks menu, and you fire the loader with the new query parameters/other info. If the loader is already running, you can cancel it and start a new one etc.